# JQuery - show div and all child label elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML:

```
<div id="summarySpan" style="padding-left: 20px" hidden>
    <label id="currentStatusSummary" style="padding-left: 20px" />
    <br />
    <label id="currentMonitoringSummary" style="padding-left: 20px" />
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$("#currentStatusSummary").text(returnedData.CurrentStatusSummary);
$("#currentMonitoringSummary").text(returnedData.CurrentMonitoringSummary);
$("#summarySpan").show().children().show();
```

For a reason I am unfamiliar with, only the first label (with ID currentStatusSummary) is shown when the JS code executes.

Can someone please explain the reason for this and help me resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `hidden` is an invalid attribute. Secondly, you should probably close your `label` tags. Finally, you only need to hide and show the parent element (if the container is hidden, its content is too).

```
<div id="summarySpan" style="padding-left: 20px; display: none;">
    <label id="currentStatusSummary" style="padding-left: 20px"></label>
    <br />
    <label id="currentMonitoringSummary" style="padding-left: 20px"></label>
</div>

$("#currentStatusSummary").text(returnedData.CurrentStatusSummary);
$("#currentMonitoringSummary").text(returnedData.CurrentMonitoringSummary);
$("#summarySpan").show();
```